# SQLite Trigger insert statement

Tags: sqlite, triggers

I'm curently learning how to create trigger, i have 2 tables named *transaction* and *sumtrans*. **Transaction** table has schema named *amount*, *tdate* and *type* that consist of 2 option **income/outcome**.
Then another table is only *month*, *income* and *outcome*. Purpose of this table is only to contain the total amount of income/outcome in the other table by month. So i create this trigger to automatically insert the sum to the table sumtrans.

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXIST sumcalc_income
 AFTER INSERT ON [transaction]
 FOR EACH ROW
 WHEN
 SELECT sum(income) FROM amount.transaction
 WHERE strftime (%Y-%m,now,start of month)
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO income.sumtrans
    DEFAULT VALUES
    END;
 END;
```

My question is

1. Did i do it right?
2. I took the refference from [this site](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html). At this [insert statement,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROMBB.png) should i do with **DEFAULT VALUES** or use the other?
3. Should I create another trigger to do it with the **Outcome** value? or can I combine it? if it can how can I do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You probably want UPDATE instead of INSERT. And this is not valid SQL. And why do you want to store the sums in a table, instead of computing them when needed?

Comment: @CL. This database is for my android apps. Maybe i will also use UPDATE. Sorry if it not valid i just getting started with it. SUMs is needed because I wanna create a function in Android from them to comparing and doing another calculation.